# Cannot pass struct pointer as function argument in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile some code but I keep getting the error:

> unknown type name ‘ *label*’;

I've declared these structures inside main, I'm not sure why I'm getting this.
I'm declaring each function prototype before the main, then function declarations after main.

I think I remember doing this, shouldn't I be able to? I'm not sure how I would declare these structs earlier.

My code:

```
void greyScale(Image* image);
void findMaxMin(Pixel** colour,Pixel* max,Pixel* min);
void strech(Image* image);
void findEffect(Image* image,char effect[20]);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char effect[20];

    /*file i/o stuff*/

    typedef struct Pixel{
      int red;
      int green;
      int blue;
    } Pixel;

    typedef struct Imagem{
      int width;
      int height;
      Pixel **pixel;
    } Image;

    Image *image;

    /*reads files, calls functions etc..*/

    return 0;
}

void greyScale(Image* image)
{
   /*code*/
}

void findMaxMin(Pixel** colour,Pixel* max,Pixel* min);
{
   /*code*/
}    

void strech(Image* image);
{
   /*code*/
}   

void findEffect(Image* image,char effect[20]);
{
   /*code*/
}
```

Comment: Without seeing your code, there's no way to tell what you're doing wrong.

Comment: can you post what you have so it make more sense

Comment: Sorry, I'll do it in a minute

Comment: What I can extrapolate from your explanation: you should declare the structure *before* function declaration.

Comment: @dbush posted part of the code

Comment: it may worth changing the struct `Pixel` to 3 `char`s instead of 3 `int`s, and move the `pixel` pointer in the `Image` struct up to make them more compact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this reference [C_structures](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_structures.htm)

Move you typedefs outside

```
typedef struct Pixel{
  int red;
  int green;
  int blue;
} Pixel;

typedef struct Imagem{
  int width;
  int height;
  Pixel **pixel;
} Image;

void greyScale(Image* image);

void findMaxMin(Pixel** colour,Pixel* max,Pixel* min);

void strech(Image* image);

void findEffect(Image* image,char effect[20]);
```

Comment: Should I declare these structs outside main?

Comment: @GoetheGrimm. Yes. I have updated my answer. Please don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You define your structs inside of `main`, so they're only viewable in that function.  These definitions need to be at the top level.

```
typedef struct Pixel{
  int red;
  int green;
  int blue;
} Pixel;

typedef struct Imagem{
  int width;
  int height;
  Pixel **pixel;
} Image;

void greyScale(Image* image);

void findMaxMin(Pixel** colour,Pixel* max,Pixel* min);

void strech(Image* image);

void findEffect(Image* image,char effect[20]);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ...
}

...
```

Now they're defined before they're used so they are available.